# How to add predicate to multiparam class in haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

GHC complains on this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class Test a b where
    data Data a b
    data Marker a b
    test :: Marker a b -> Bool

work :: (Test a b, Test a2 b2) => Data a b -> Data a2 b2 
work =
    let (m :: Marker a2 b2) = undefined
    in if test m then undefined else undefined
```

With the message:

```
You cannot bind scoped type variables `a2', `b2'
  in a pattern binding signature
In the pattern: m :: Marker a2 b2
```

I don't want to move actual functionality of `work` function into `Test` class because `test` predicate is used in several functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles if you bring the type variables into scope:

```
work :: forall a b a2 b2. (Test a b, Test a2 b2) => Data a b -> Data a2 b2 
work =
    let (m :: Marker a2 b2) = undefined
    in if test m then undefined else undefined
```

without the explicit `forall`, the type variables `a2` and `b2` in the let-binding are fresh type variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use `forall a b a2 b2.` as a2, b2 in `Marker a2 b2` will treated as new. Using `forall` will bring them into scope:

```
work :: forall a b a2 b2. (Test a b, Test a2 b2) => Data a b -> Data a2 b2
```

More on [forall keyword](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#The_forall_keyword)